# "No access to API product" error when trying to reach Data Connector API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I'm experiencing issues when trying to call the [Data Connector API](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-data-connector-api-available-public-beta) via Postman.
When executing the POST request to submit a data request, Postman returns the following error:

```
    "developerMessage": "The client_id specified does not have access to the api product",
    "moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
    "errorCode": "AUTH-001"
```

Here is what I've tried:

- I have created a Forge app which has access to all APIs.
- The user has Executive Overview permissions within the account (which has many projects).
- I call the API using a 3-legged auth token with data:read, data:write and data:create scopes.

This is the code I'm using (exported from Postman):

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data-connector/v1/accounts/<ACCOUNT_ID>/requests' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <BEARER_TOKEN>' \
--data-raw '
{
    "description": "Test Extract",
    "scheduleInterval": "ONE_TIME",
    "effectiveFrom": "2021-01-30T12:00:00Z",
    "serviceGroups": ["admin", "checklists", "dailylogs", "issues", "locations", "submittals", "cost", "rfis"]
}'
```

Your help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I got the exact same error today. Is the API not working due to Christmas holiday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jro, Simon, Data Connector API is now accessible. Could you give it a try if it can work at your side? Thank you for your patience and any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue as yours, I don't know if the API is really public or not.

Hope that someone from Adesk forge team could answer us.

Comment: it should be working now. Could you give it a try? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

yes, this API is public beta now. We are working with engineer team and will get back to you soon. Our apology for the issue!